# to get string having special charater using regex

Tags: python, regex

```
import re 
strg = "what is AM&I"
z= re.sub(r'&', '', strg)
# pattern = r'(?:[A-Z]\.)+'
# pattern = r'\b(?:[A-Z][a-z]*){2,}'
regex = re.compile('[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]')
print regex
print regex.search(strg)
```

i need to get the output as AM&I

Comment: Please, could you add some more details as what you are trying to do? And why are the first two patterns commented out?

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you want AM&I as output just do `print('AM&I')` or be more specific about your input/ouput.

Answer (score 2):

This regular expression

```
regex = re.compile(r'(\S*[@_!#$%^&*()<>?/\|}{~:]\S*)')
```

will look for "words" (meaning strings of nonblank characters) that contain at least one of the special characters you are looking for.

```
>>> strg = "what is AM&I"
>>> m=regex.search(strg)
>>> m.group(1)
'AM&I'
```

though with only one example to go on it is very likely that this will fail to match other things you are looking for (false negatives) or will return things you are not really looking for (false positives).